# Which browser is used when we use SharePoint Export To Excel Functionality?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

I have implemented single sign on functionality on SharePoint server 2019 but when I am trying to Export To Excel SharePoint list, its showing some script error (it could be because I used JS which is not supported in IE). So can you please confirm which browser is used when used MS Office software to authenticate the user.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried to set different default browsers(Chrome, Edge etc.) but it is showing the error of script.

Comment: What error did you get? For other site collections without custom scripts, does the same issue exist when using "Export To Excel"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
 I am using web socket communication and I try to open  query.iqy file then it is showing error. But the single sign on is working perfectly in chrome and MS edge as websocket is not supported in IE browser then I guess it could be excel is trying to open in IE that is why I asked which browser is used by MS excel when I try to open query.iqy file.

Comment: This issue is in all microsoft documents e.g PPT, Word, Excel etc.

Comment: So, when you use Chrome and Edge, no error displayed, this issue just happens on IE, is it right?

Comment: No actually, Issue is when I try to open the .iqy (SharePoint list export to excel) file it is authenticating again so my question is when it is authenticating then which browser is taken by excel.

Comment: I have got the answer that it depends on which ms office version you are using e.g office 2016,19 uses internet explorer. So its cleared that it uses internet explorer browser.

Reference link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins